# binding to specific ip address in elasticsearch 5

Tags: networking, elasticsearch

I have tried several combinations of proposed configurations I found either in the official documentation or the internet. However, I'm keep getting the same error shown below regardless of the configuration.

```
[2016-12-14T13:47:37,706][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [vc6lzXh] no plugins loaded
[2016-12-14T13:47:43,048][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] initialized
[2016-12-14T13:47:43,054][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [vc6lzXh] starting ...
[2016-12-14T13:47:43,495][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [vc6lzXh] publish_address {192.168.34.84:9300}, bound_addresses {[::1]:9300}, {127.0.0.1:9300}
[2016-12-14T13:47:43,514][INFO ][o.e.b.BootstrapCheck     ] [vc6lzXh] bound or publishing to a non-loopback or non-link-local address, enforcing bootstrap checks
ERROR: bootstrap checks failed
max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]
[2016-12-14T13:47:43,538][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [vc6lzXh] stopping ...
[2016-12-14T13:47:43,680][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [vc6lzXh] stopped
[2016-12-14T13:47:43,681][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [vc6lzXh] closing ...
[2016-12-14T13:47:43,700][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [vc6lzXh] closed
```

Elasticsearch v5.1.1 is installed in a virtual machine which has a bridged ip address, `192.168.34.84`

The configurations I've tried are as follows:
1.

```
network.host, 192.168.34.84
```

2.

```
network.host: 192.168.34.84
network.public_host: 192.168.34.84
```

3.

```
network.bind_host: 192.168.34.84
```

4.

```
network.bind_host: 0.0.0.0
network.publish_host: 192.168.34.84
```

None of these did work for me. I guess there are significant changes in v5.11. any help?

Comment: Is that the whole error ?

Comment: yes, there are only two lines of log according to this.

Comment: You mean in the console which you started ES?

Comment: I updated the question to give more error log

Comment: I've updated the answer, under the EDIT part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the the [Bootstrap Checks](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/bootstrap-checks.html), make sure you've got the important settings set in your machine.

Setting your `network.host` to something like this, where `network.bind_host` and `network.public_host` would pick up the value of `network.host` by default:

```
network.host: 192.168.34.84
```

Try having only the above property set , without the others. Maybe you could have a look at these for more:

- [Blog Post](https://www.elastic.co/blog/bootstrap_checks_annoying_instead_of_devastating)
- [Network Settings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html#advanced-network-settings)

**EDIT:**

So according to your logs, you have to increase `vm.max_map_count` to 262144 where you set this, as a root user in your machine:

```
sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
```

Have a look at the details [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/vm-max-map-count.html) about the VM.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I've already tried setting `network.host` only but the result is same.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research and trying few solution I found this solution working. In our case we wanted to run our elastic search on one of our dev server instead of local machine.

***network.host***
The node will bind to this hostname or IP address and publish (advertise) this host to other nodes in the cluster. Accepts an IP address, hostname, a special value, or an array of any combination of these. Note that any values containing a : (e.g., an IPv6 address or containing one of the special values) must be quoted because : is a special character in YAML. 0.0.0.0 is an acceptable IP address and will bind to all network interfaces. The value 0 has the same effect as the value 0.0.0.0.

Open this configuration page **elasticsearch.yml**
network.host: "192.168.1.1" // Your desired TP address

After changing the values restart your elasticsearch serer and it will resolve the issue.
Hope it helps.